# Bind 2 dataframes with dataframes elements

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, rbind

I need to bind 2 dataframes that contain dataframe as element. The problem - inlayed dataframes column names could be different, and number of columns could be different. That's the result I need:

[image]

Here is my data:

```
issue_desc_1 <- data.frame(
                   MinAvailableMb = 50,
                   Threshold = 100
                   )

issues.df_1 <- data.frame(
    IssueId = 1,
    IssueSubId = 1,
    Categories = "Cat1",
    Solution = "Sol1",
    Level = 'Critical',
    AffectedObjects = "comp1.domain.local",
    Arguments = I(issue_desc_1)
)


issue_desc_2 <- data.frame(
                     MaxCommitedGB = 82,
                     RamSize = 64,
                     Threshold = 64
)

    
issues.df_2 <- data.frame(
    IssueId = 1,
    IssueSubId = 2,
    Categories = "Cat1",
    Solution = "Sol1",
    Level = 'Critical',
    AffectedObjects = "comp2.domain.local",
    Arguments = I(issue_desc_2)
)
```

Arguments element is dataframe here.

I am trying different ways to bind dataframes but I'm getting errors.

`rbind(issues.df_1, issues.df_2)` and `rbind(issues.df_1, issues.df_2, fill = T)`

Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ri, , value = list(MaxCommitedGB = 82,  :
provided 3 variables to replace 2 variables
Error in dim(rvec) <- dim(x) :
dims [product 6] do not match the length of object [2]

`plyr::rbind.fill(issues.df_1, issues.df_2)`

Error in allocate_column(df[[var]], nrows, dfs, var) :
Data frame column 'Arguments' not supported by rbind.fill

`bind_rows(issues.df_1, issues.df_2)`

Error in dim(rvec) <- dim(x) :
dims [product 8] do not match the length of object [4]

How to create dataframe I need from 2 dataframes I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is - to use tibble instead of data.frame. That case command `dplyr::bind_rows(issues.df_1, issues.df_2)` gives correct result.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)


issue_desc_1 <- tibble(
                   MinAvailableMb = 50,
                   Threshold = 100
                   )

issues.df_1 <- tibble(
    IssueId = 1,
    IssueSubId = 1,
    Categories = "Cat1",
    Solution = "Sol1",
    Level = 'Critical',
    AffectedObjects = "comp1.domain.local",
    Arguments = (issue_desc_1)
)


issue_desc_2 <- tibble(
                     MaxCommitedGB = 82,
                     RamSize = 64,
                     Threshold = 64
)

issues.df_2 <- tibble(
    IssueId = 1,
    IssueSubId = 2,
    Categories = "Cat1",
    Solution = "Sol1",
    Level = 'Critical',
    AffectedObjects = "comp2.domain.local",
    Arguments = (issue_desc_2)
)


dplyr::bind_rows(issues.df_1, issues.df_2)
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  IssueId IssueSubId Categories Solution Level    AffectedObjects    Arguments$MinAvailableMb $Threshold $MaxCommitedGB $RamSize
    <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                                 <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>
1       1          1 Cat1       Sol1     Critical comp1.domain.local                       50        100             NA       NA
2       1          2 Cat1       Sol1     Critical comp2.domain.local                       NA         64             82       64
```